How to append table by using indirect reference in Power Query?
I have a table that contain list of other table name that I would like to append its table.
For examples
TableABC
Column1 contains (All are other table name as text)
Table1
Table2
Table3
I would like to append Table1,Table2,Table3 by using reference only TableABC
I try
= Table.Combine({TableABC}) or
= Table.Combine(TableABC)
It doesn't work.
Please help. Thank you
I try
= Table.Combine({TableABC}) or
= Table.Combine(TableABC)
I expect convert to >> =Table.Combine({#"Table1", #"Table2", #"Table3"})

xxx=SometableName[ColumnNameContainingTableNames],
combined=Table.Combine(List.Transform(xxx, each Record.Field(Record.SelectFields(#shared,{_}),_)))
in combined

